# ag-grid React date filter value inputs to dd/mm/yyyy from mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, datefilter

while working in ag-grid table (React). the columndefs filter is **filter: 'agDateColumnFilter'** is active.
the placeholder of the filter is in mm/dd/yyyy [ag-grid default date filter placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQjwM.png)  as shown in the picture but we need it as dd/mm/yyyy as we have in table row records.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-1sf6fu?file=index.js

**Placeholder of column filter of date to be**
from mm/dd/yyyy
to dd/mm/yyyy

i tried the formatting but its not altering the filters default values.
by using this https://blog.ag-grid.com/valueformatters-part-2/#filter-dates.